# To find the convex planar region minimizing diameter when area and perimeter are given

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

The basic question is to find that planar convex region for which diameter is a minimum when area and perimeter are specified.

A partial answer is given here: http://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2012/11/maximizing-and-minimizing-diameter-ii.html which goes:
If the specified perimeter is *not more than that of the Reuleaux triangle* with the specified area, then, the required planar convex region is a region of constant width. The following question remains, as was noted in the above-linked page:

**Question:** For specified area $A$ and perimeter $P$ where $P$ is greater than the perimeter of the Reuleaux triangle of area $A$, which planar convex shape minimizes diameter?

When the specified $P$ is steadily increased keeping $A$ fixed, will an ellipse become the answer at any stage?

Note: higher dimensional analogs to the questions could also be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2000 paper *Inequalities for Convex Sets,* by Paul R. Scott and Poh Way Awyong, lists various inequalities on 2D convex bodies as described [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/016_99_JIPAM/016_99_www.pdf); for your question you can see the state of the research at that time in the first of the three-inequality sections, with some extremal sets listed for their assorted bounds.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for what appears to be a very comprehensive reference.